# clone failing drive without losing redundancy on Synology NAS

Tags: raid, nas, btrfs, synology-diskstation

I have a Synology NAS (DS416play running DSM 6.2) configured as SHR with 1 drive redundancy.

One of the drives has been flagged as failing but is not yet showing any kind of errors. I could simply pull it out and insert a new one but, from past experience, I'd then have perhaps a week of no redundancy during data scrubbing.

The NAS has USB so I wonder: could I temporarily attach a new drive externally and "pre-clone" onto it somehow in order to minimise the amount of time with no redundancy?

In case it is relevant, the new drive is different/larger (8TB vs 6TB).

Comment: Be careful to make sure that the new drive does not use [SMR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shingled_magnetic_recording), which has proven troublesome for NAS devices.

Comment: Thanks, yes I won't be buying more WD since their shenanigans with Red (I narrowly avoided ending up with an SMR a couple of years ago but managed to cancel the order). I'm slowly replacing with [Toshiba N300](https://www.canvio.jp/en/support/download/hdd/ot_ihdd/n300.htm). They do run several degrees hotter but they also don't cost as much...

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative option, temporary changing some parameters can drastically speed up the raid expansion in some cases (for example, from 10 days to 16 hours).

You can use `cat /proc/mdstat` and `mdadm --detail /dev/mdX` to find the raid device you are expanding. Often it is `md2`, while other are ~2GB mirrored system partitions.

Write down current values first to restore them later.

```
$ cat /sys/block/md2/md/stripe_cache_size
$ cat /proc/sys/dev/raid/speed_limit_min
$ cat /sys/block/md2/queue/read_ahead_kb
$ cat /sys/block/md2/md/sync_max

$ echo 32768 > /sys/block/md2/md/stripe_cache_size
$ echo 50000 > /proc/sys/dev/raid/speed_limit_min
$ echo 32768 > /sys/block/md2/queue/read_ahead_kb
$ echo max   > /sys/block/md2/md/sync_max
```

`stripe_cache_size` is the max value, and it takes up 32Mib to synchronize read/write operations while the array is degraded.

`speed_limit_min` is a hint that you want more focus on the sync-expansion task. It also exists as a [GUI option](https://kb.synology.com/en-us/DSM/help/DSM/StorageManager/storage_pool_adjust_resync_speed?version=7) in DSM 6 and 7.

`read_ahead_kb` is how far ahead of a read request the drive array will preload.

`sync_max` is the numbers of sectors that indicate a range within the array where check/repair will operate (there is also a sync_min). This one seems to give the most impact for some.

Sources:

- https://gist.github.com/fbartho/2cb998dc1f10d13c124bf736286fd757
- https://community.synology.com/enu/forum/1/post/130936
- https://eprints.bbk.ac.uk/id/eprint/30457/1/2020-01-03-accelerating-synology-raid-6-reshapes.markdown
- https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.15/admin-guide/md.html
- https://kb.synology.com/en-us/DSM/help/DSM/StorageManager/storage_pool_adjust_resync_speed?version=7

Comment: thanks, although this doesn't address my question (method to clone disk without degrading the array at all, rather than how to minimise rebuild time after degrading it), your answer may help others. I guess it should be all disks not just `md2`? sync_max=max is the default now and my speed_limit_min=300000. Is such a large `read_ahead_kb` useful (eg. my `max_sectors_kb` is 512 and the default `read_ahead_kb` is different for each of my disk models)?

Comment: I couldn't find an easy way to pre-clone the drive myself, so this was the next viable option. I was surprised with the results it had in the gist and its comments, but did not try it myself yet.

My example was taken from a raid5 configuration, where md2 was the actual raid5 that was expanding, while md0 and md1 were ~2GB system partitions, so configuring them too is most likely unnecessary.

Comment: In theory, large `read_ahead_kb` can be useful, since it increases read-speed for workloads where you're scanning most of the drive. But I did not see cases of it being used and measured by itself during the expansion, so it might be a case of "trying a bit everything".

Answer (score 0):

DSM 7 adds a "[replace drive](https://kb.synology.com/en-global/DSM/help/DSM/StorageManager/storage_pool_expand_replace_disk?version=7)" feature.

If I had a spare drive bay, this would do what I asked for.

Sadly, it doesn't appear to work with a USB-attached disk.